# Installing Conda and Python from RStudio (reticulate)

Tags: reticulate

I'm having problems importing the `scipy` module even though it was installed to the `r-reticulate` environment.

Specific error message:

```
> scipy <- import("scipy")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

List of conda envs:

```
> conda_list()
          name                                                              python
1     untitled                  /Users/williamchiu/.conda/envs/untitled/bin/python
2  r-miniconda                   /Users/williamchiu/Library/r-miniconda/bin/python
3 r-reticulate /Users/williamchiu/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
4    anaconda3                             /Users/williamchiu/anaconda3/bin/python
5 r-reticulate           /Users/williamchiu/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
```

Screen dump:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(reticulate)
> 
> # create a new environment 
> conda_create("r-reticulate")
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/williamchiu/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate

  added / updated specs:
    - python


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py38_0         156 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         156 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/osx-64::ca-certificates-2019.11.27-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/osx-64::certifi-2019.11.28-py38_0
  libcxx             pkgs/main/osx-64::libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1
  libcxxabi          pkgs/main/osx-64::libcxxabi-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1
  libedit            pkgs/main/osx-64::libedit-3.1.20181209-hb402a30_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/osx-64::libffi-3.2.1-h475c297_4
  ncurses            pkgs/main/osx-64::ncurses-6.1-h0a44026_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1d-h1de35cc_3
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-19.3.1-py38_0
  python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.8.1-h359304d_1
  readline           pkgs/main/osx-64::readline-7.0-h1de35cc_5
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-44.0.0-py38_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/osx-64::sqlite-3.30.1-ha441bb4_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tk-8.6.8-ha441bb4_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.33.6-py38_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::xz-5.2.4-h1de35cc_4
  zlib               pkgs/main/osx-64::zlib-1.2.11-h1de35cc_3



Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2019.11.28   | 156 KB    | ########## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate r-reticulate
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

[1] "/Users/williamchiu/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python"
> 
> # install SciPy
> conda_install("r-reticulate", "scipy")
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

# All requested packages already installed.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/williamchiu/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate

  added / updated specs:
    - python
    - scipy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py38_0         148 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         148 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  libblas            conda-forge/osx-64::libblas-3.8.0-14_openblas
  libcblas           conda-forge/osx-64::libcblas-3.8.0-14_openblas
  libgfortran        conda-forge/osx-64::libgfortran-4.0.0-2
  liblapack          conda-forge/osx-64::liblapack-3.8.0-14_openblas
  libopenblas        conda-forge/osx-64::libopenblas-0.3.7-h3d69b6c_6
  llvm-openmp        conda-forge/osx-64::llvm-openmp-9.0.1-h28b9765_1
  numpy              conda-forge/osx-64::numpy-1.17.3-py38hde6bac1_0
  scipy              conda-forge/osx-64::scipy-1.4.1-py38h82752d6_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.11.27~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
  libcxx                 pkgs/main::libcxx-4.0.1-hcfea43d_1 --> conda-forge::libcxx-9.0.1-1

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> conda-forge
  openssl              pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-h1de35cc_3 --> conda-forge::openssl-1.1.1d-h0b31af3_0



Downloading and Extracting Packages
certifi-2019.11.28   | 148 KB    | ########## | 100% 
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
> 
> use_condaenv('r-reticulate')
> 
> # import SciPy (it will be automatically discovered in "r-reticulate")
> scipy <- import("scipy")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
> Sys.info()
                                                                                           sysname 
                                                                                          "Darwin" 
                                                                                           release 
                                                                                          "19.2.0" 
                                                                                           version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64" 
                                                                                          nodename 
                                                                      "Williams-MacBook-Pro.local" 
                                                                                           machine 
                                                                                          "x86_64" 
                                                                                             login 
                                                                                            "root" 
                                                                                              user 
                                                                                     "williamchiu" 
                                                                                    effective_user 
                                                                                     "williamchiu"
```